# VMWare ESXi 4.0 Two datastores One Virtual Machine

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a physical machine that has two separate raid arrays, one for data and one for the OS. I would like to convert the server to a Virtual machine to run on an ESXi server. However the ESXi server does not have a single datastore large enough for the contents of both arrays. Is it possible to host the boot drive on one datastore and the data drive on another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep this is very possible. When you are adding the second hard drive it will give you the option to keep the drive with the VM or to specify the data store that it is on. I think it's the second or third screen when adding a drive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.  You can either create a new virtual disk or use an existing virtual disk at which point it will ask you which datastore it should be created or loaded from.  I just tested this on 2 different datastores with my Windows XP VM on ESXi 4.0, and it works with no problems.